# Web API parameters binding

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have this action in Web Api controller:

```
public Data GetData(ComplexModel model)
```

and model is

```
class ComplexModel
{
     Guid Guid1 { get; set;}
     Guid Guid2 { get; set;}
     string String1 { get; set;}
}
```

i would like to specify custom binder for Guid type such as empty string or null would bind to empty guid and would like not use nullable type. Was trying to register model binder like this:

```
var pb = configuration.ParameterBindingRules;
pb.Insert(0, typeof(Guid), param => param.BindWithModelBinding(new GuidBinder()));
```

but it is not called and I am getting invalid model state with error message that empty string cant be converted to type Guid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember, `ParameterBindingRules` checks the controller action parameter itself (`ComplexModel` in your case), *not* the contents of the parameter. You'd need to register a parameter binding against `ComplexModel` and do any processing with the custom binder to validate the model instance. Seems like you're better off making the `Guid` properties nullable despite your reluctance to do so.